# JavaFX координаты мыши относительно контрола

Tags: java, javafx

В программе используется панель(Pane), и для неё я создал слушателя перемещения мыши:

```
setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        double x = e.getX();
        double y = e.getY();
    });
```

В самом слушателе я получил координаты мыши, но над этой панелью.
У меня есть еще одна панель, которая включает вышеописанную панель. Как получить координаты мыши над второй панелью, при этом находясь в слушателе другой, первой панели?

Пример подробнее:

```
   public class TestControl extends Pane{
        private Pane parent;
        public TestControl(Pane p){
            super();
            parent = p;

            setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                // e.getX(), e.getY() - координаты мыши над TestControl
                // как здесь получить координаты мыши над parent?
            });
        }
    };
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно получить координаты относительно родительского элемента.

```
Point2D point2D = button.localToParent(event.getX(), event.getY());
System.out.println(point2D.getX() + " : "+point2D.getY());
```

Чтобы получить более сложное поведение, можно использовать *localToScene*, тогда координаты переведутся в координаты относительно сцены, а не родительского элемента.
Чтобы получить координаты относительно любого элемента, нужно найти их координаты для какого-то общего элемента, сцены или даже экрана, а потом найти их разницу.

```
Bounds bounds = button.localToParent(node.getLayoutBounds());

double x = event.getX() + bounds.getMinX();
double y = event.getY() + bounds.getMinY();
```

Так можно найти относительные координаты к любому элементу на сцене. Но я не уверен в том как именно это работает с большой вложенностью